# Why does ubuntu chrome does NOT ask to unlock keyring to view saved passwords?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, google-chrome, password

On MAC if you want to view saved passwords on Ubuntu it will ask you for keyring password all the time.

On Ubuntu 18.04 + gnome, Chrome did not **ask** for password when I wanted to view saved passwords.

I even locked the keyring in seahorse gui and then started chrome and yet showed me passwords without asking to unlock the keyring.

Lastly, `--password-store=` option is not on the command line and the Ubuntu keyring **does** have entries for `Chrome Safe Storage` and `Chrome Safe Storage Control` .

I do **not** think the Chrome hash is cached after getting it from the keyring before hand.

Comment: My guess is that Chrome stores its own passwords. As mentioned in the other comment: Chrome, being proprietary software, is not officially supported in Ubuntu, but the upstream `chromium-browser` is.  Chromium is the open source browser developed by Google, before adding all of the closed-source proprietary code to make Chrome that is capable of doing only God knows what

Comment: Chrome, Chromium, and Firefox all store their own passwords without using Seahorse. Look in the browser's Settings menu.

Comment: Chromes **does** use the keyring. Seahorse is just an interface. In fact the chrome command line option `--password-store=` has 3 options `basic` , `gnome` and `kde`. When nothing is on the command line it goes with the `gnome` keyring. So how do you **auto** lock the keyring after some inactivity ?

Comment: From [Google Chrome Help > Manage Passwords > How Chrome saves and syncs passwords](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606):  *How Chrome saves your passwords depends on whether you want to store and use them across devices. When synced, passwords can be used on Chrome on all your devices, and across some apps on your Android devices. When sync is turned on for passwords in Chrome, your passwords are saved to your Google Account. **Otherwise, your passwords are only stored on Chrome on your computer.*** - This says nothing about using the OS's keyring

Comment: @Nmath, maybe that specific page does not mention **local** storage. Do you think it stores it in a plain text file **locally** ? Research `-password-store=` in my comment above.